# Dynamic JSON object is not passing to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

On Button Click I am getting `lineItems` as json object and passing it to MVC Action Method. In C# I get lineItems count = 1 mean array is passing but values inside line item

As shown in image below I am getting all values but not inner objects
[image]

```
  $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var lineItems = [];
            $.each(extractGetSectionData('adults'), function (index, value) {
                lineItems.push(value);
            });
            $.each(extractGetSectionData('children'), function (index, value) {
                lineItems.push(value);
            });
            $.each(extractGetSectionData('seniors'), function (index, value) {
                lineItems.push(value);
            });

            console.log(lineItems);

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/CompleteOrder",
                dataType: "JSON",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    ApplicationId: '',
                    ApiKey: '',
                    SendTicketsSms: true,
                    FirstName: $("#field-billing-first-name").val(),
                    LastName: $("#field-billing-last-name").val(),
                    Address: '',
                    City: '',
                    State: '',
                    PostalCode: $("#field-billing-postal-code").val(),
                    Country: $("#field-payment-card-number").val(), //http://www.theodora.com/country_digraphs.html
                    Email: $("#field-delivery-email").val(),
                    Phone: '',

                    CcNumberEncrypted: $("#field-payment-card-number").val(),
                    CcExpiryMonthEncrypted: $("#field-payment-expires-on").val(), //"1"
                    CcExpiryYearEncrypted: $("#field-payment-expires-on-year").val(), //"2016"
                    CcCvvEncrypted: $("#field-payment-security-code").val(), //"123"
                    CcZipCodeEncrypted: "", //"76020"

                    LineItems: lineItems
                }
            }).done(function(data) {

                document.write("Success :" + data.Success + "<br>");
                document.write("ResponseCode :" + data.ResponseCode + "<br>");
                document.write("ResponseReason :" + data.ResponseReason + "<br><br><br>");

                document.write("OrderIdentifier :" + data.OrderIdentifier + "<br>");
                document.write("OrderNumber :" + data.OrderNumber + "<br>");
                document.write("GrandTotal :" + data.GrandTotal + "<br>");
            });


        });




function extractGetSectionData(slug) {

    var sectionId = 123; 

    var sectionRows = $(".form-section-passes").find("div[data-slug='" + slug + "']");

    var data = [];

    sectionRows.each(function () {
        var firstName = $(this).find("input[id*='[first-name]']").val();
        var lastName = $(this).find("input[id*='[last-name]']").val();
        var country = $(this).find("select[id*='[country]']").val();

        data.push({
            OpenTicketSectionId: sectionId, //Adult
            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            CountryOfOrigin: country,
        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

C# Models

```
 public class CompleteOrderRequestLineItem
    {
        public int OpenTicketSectionId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
    }




     public class CompleteOrderRequest
        {
            public Guid ApiKey { get; set; }
            public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }

            public bool SendTicketsSms { get; set; }

            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }



            public string CcNumberEncrypted { get; set; }
            public string CcExpiryMonthEncrypted { get; set; }
            public string CcExpiryYearEncrypted { get; set; }
            public string CcCvvEncrypted { get; set; }
            public string CcZipCodeEncrypted { get; set; }

            public List<CompleteOrderRequestLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
        }


        public class CompleteOrderRequestLineItem
        {
            public int OpenTicketSectionId { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: where is your MVC controller?

Comment: Did you mark the controller method with [HttpPost] attribute?

Comment: yes it is coming on MVC controller and all other fields are also coming on MVC but only lineitems innner object is showing null seems like that is not maping... CompleteOrderRequestLineItem class

Comment: null objects or objects with all null fields?

Comment: try `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` on your `$.ajax`

Comment: Not clear why you would not just generate your controls with the correct names and just use `$(yourForm).serialize()`, but if you post back an array in this format, yo need to include the following ajax options: `traditional: true, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", data: JSON.stringify(yourObject),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>
> **The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server**. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string)

If you need to send JSON data to server, try `contentType` instead:

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then
>   it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header.

Try `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/CompleteOrder",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                ApplicationId: '',
                ApiKey: '',
                SendTicketsSms: true,
                FirstName: $("#field-billing-first-name").val(),
                LastName: $("#field-billing-last-name").val(),
                Address: '',
                City: '',
                State: '',
                PostalCode: $("#field-billing-postal-code").val(),
                Country: $("#field-payment-card-number").val(), //http://www.theodora.com/country_digraphs.html
                Email: $("#field-delivery-email").val(),
                Phone: '',

                CcNumberEncrypted: $("#field-payment-card-number").val(),
                CcExpiryMonthEncrypted: $("#field-payment-expires-on").val(), //"1"
                CcExpiryYearEncrypted: $("#field-payment-expires-on-year").val(), //"2016"
                CcCvvEncrypted: $("#field-payment-security-code").val(), //"123"
                CcZipCodeEncrypted: "", //"76020"

                LineItems: lineItems
            })
        })
```

Comment: I just edit question with image

Comment: @SOF User: did you try contentType ?

Comment: @SOF User: I forgot that you also have to use JSON.stringify to convert javascript object to JSON string. See updated answer.